# corrplot function | Method is not a graphical parameter

Tags: r

I've been using the corrplot function, and it has worked fine until this morning. Note: I did update Anaconda.

> Here is a screenshot of the code (which worked fine yesterday

[image: ):]

Essentially, I have the following code:

```
corrplot(cor(fattrain[ , 1:18]), method = "pie", type = "lower")
```

The error that I get is:

```
"Method is not a graphical parameter"
```

Why is this so? The code worked fine, yesterday? I've made no changes to the data/data types.

Comment: Could be that some function is getting masked.  Can you show the `dput(fattrain[, 1:18])`.  It does with `corrplot(cor(mtcars), method = "pie", type = "lower")`

Comment: Or when you installed anaconda, are you now having the same R version and package versions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.